# Why is Flask-wtforms pushing sidebar below form content

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

`registration.html` and `home.html` page (among others) inherit from the same `layout.html`. Everything appears to be set up correctly; sidebar is showing to the right on all pages except where I'm using wtforms. This appears to not be the case for others.

**home.html**

[image]

**register.html**

[image]

**layout.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">

    {% if title %}
        <title> ANC - {{ title }} </title>
    {% else %}
        <title>All New Colors</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-yellow fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/"><img src='static/img/anc-logo-nav.png'></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
        <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center">
        <img style = "padding-top: 3vh; padding-bottom: 8vh;" src = "static/img/website_logo_transparent_background.png">
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
      {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
            {{ message }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content-section">
        <h3>Popular Tags</h3>
        <p class='text-muted'>Find additional topics using the search bar.
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">Latest Posts</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">Career</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">Education</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">Finance</li>
          </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**register.html**

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class='content-section'>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.confirm_password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div> 
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Sign In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the bootstrap css but I'm not sure how to fix or override that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `closing div </div>` before `closing </form>`

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}"> -->
</head>
<body>
<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-yellow fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/"><img src='static/img/anc-logo-nav.png'></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
        <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center">
        <img style = "padding-top: 3vh; padding-bottom: 8vh;" src = "static/img/website_logo_transparent_background.png">
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

      <div class='content-section'>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }} {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }} {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.password.label(class="form-control-label") }} {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.confirm_password.label(class="form-control-label") }} {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }} \
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="border-top pt-3">
    <small class="text-muted">
            Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Sign In</a>
        </small>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content-section">
        <h3>Popular Tags</h3>
        <p class='text-muted'>Find additional topics using the search bar.
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">Latest Posts</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">Career</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">Education</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">Finance</li>
          </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```